# How to support multiple app configs in Rider

Tags: c#, .net, rider

So I'm building a .net app in rider.

.Net has the concept of a "config file"... the app.config file and then within that it supports "sub configs" that can override and add parameters.

[image: Illustration of my config files]

Now the questions is how do run my application with one of these config files selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you spend some time on Rider's forum, you should notice someone asked a few years ago,

https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001333940-Web-Config-Transforms

Then the developers worked on the feature,

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-10840?_ga=2.196415914.725729255.1638903644-2041891069.1638221641

and a plugin was shipped as the final work,

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10005--net-xdt-configuration-transformation-support

Comment: thanks for your response... it was more that I didn't understand the way this "config" system works, that's what my obstacle was being new to the whole c#/.net landscape. Looks like that plugin will help